# how to synchronize 2 jobs/processes

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, executorservice, executor

I am having a server application which processes 2 jobs(file processing) which are completely different flows. i invoke the client giving either job1 or job 2 so it could be either of these 2 in some interval of time .since the files are picked from a folder I want to  synchronize the jobs i.e. if for example i trigger job 2 again quickly after triggering job 2 the first time ;the files in that might not have been processed so i should not pick them up again . and also i would rather wait for the first executor (executor service ) to finish off before triggering another job/executor.

I have tried using a map where i store the job and executor and trying to synchronize the map .but I am not sure how to proceed.some code has been left out for clarity.

Server class:

```
public class ProcessServer {


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Integer port = Integer.parseInt(Configuration.getProperty("Environment", "PORT"));
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        LOG.info("Process Server listening on PORT: " + port);
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            new Thread(new ProcessEvent(socket)).start();
        }
    } catch (Throwable th) {
        LOG.error("Exception occured starting server.", th);
    }
}
}
```

ProcessEvent Class:

```
public class ProcessEvent implements Runnable {
   //code to extract argument(event/jobtype) from socket stream
            private void processEvent(Event event) {
    switch (event.getType()) {
        case 1:
            new ProcessJob1().execute(MAP1);
            break;
        case 2:
            new ProcessJob2().execute(MAP2);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Job Class 1:

```
public class ProcessJob1 extends Job {

private static Map<String, ExecutorService> isRunning = new HashMap<String, ExecutorService>();

@Override
public void execute(Map<String, Object> jobData) {

    String txn = (String)jobData.get(TYPE);
    ExecutorService executor = null;

    synchronized (isRunning) {
        executor = isRunning.get(type); 
        if (executor != null && !executor.isTerminated()) {
            return;
        }

        executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREAD_CNT);
        isRunning.put(type, executor);
    }


    File[] inputFiles = getValidFiles();
    if (inputFiles.length > 0) {
        for (File inputFile : inputFiles) {
            executor.execute(new ProcessFileTask1(inputFile));
        }
    }
    executor.shutdown();
}

}
```

Job Class 2:

```
public class ProcessJob2 extends Job {

private static ExecutorService executor = null;

@Override
public void execute(Map<String, Object> jobData) {
    if (executor != null && !executor.isTerminated()) {
        return;
    }

    executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);


    File[] inputFiles = getValidFiles();
    if (inputFiles.length > 0) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX_THREAD_CNT);
        for (File inputFile : inputFiles) {
            executor.execute(new ProcessFileTask2(inputFile));
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: the server is continuously running . i want to know how between the two jobs synchronize the executor so that it waits for the previous job to finish off first . what would even be better if i could queue the new request..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating new executors for every time you have to use one executors with single threaded approach.`Executors#newSingleThreadExecutor()`

```
public class ProcessJob1 extends Job {

private static Map<String, ExecutorService> isRunning = new HashMap<String, ExecutorService>();

private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MAX);

private static CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(0);
@Override
public void execute(Map<String, Object> jobData) {


    File[] inputFiles = getValidFiles();
    countDownLatch.await();

    if (inputFiles.length > 0) {
        countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(inputFiles.length);
        for (File inputFile : inputFiles) {
              case 1:
                  executor.execute(new ProcessFileTask1(inputFile,countDownLatch));
                  break;
              case 2:
                  executor.execute(new ProcessFileTask2(inputFile,countDownLatch));
                  break;
              default:
                  break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

You can use CountDownLatch to achieve this.

Initially it will be zero . If you call wait , it will return.

After You will reset the latch value to size of the files.

Pass the latch to `ProcessFileTask1` and call latch.countDown() once it has done its.

Next job will enter the latch.await(), it will wait until all the task will complete. If already completes it will come out immediately from await.

Instead of branching above you should branch here. So You have more control to sync thread

Comment: single / pool executor isnt a problem ..if u see the foreach:loop where i spawn the individual file tasks .i want executor to be synchronized in a way that it should wait till the first executor job has ended .

Comment: thanks , but sadly this doesnt solve my whole problem ..what is i trigger job 2 in the midst or while job 1 is still running i mean the executor service .

Comment: @avinashkr Now i have added some code to handle both

Comment: i could probably try this but processjob1 and 2 cannot be combined into a single class

Comment: to explain practically if i picked up files from the first job they will process and be moved to another folder , so if i trigger another job too soon SOME files will still be there and will be put in executorservice queue . so it will amount to DOUBLE processing

Comment: If you picked up files from the first job they will process and be moved to another folder.  If you trigger another job too soon files   will still be there and wait to put in executor . it will put the executors once first will complete

Comment: ok is there any way i can know for sure how many tasks in my executorservice have finished // or hany are still left/queued ?